# elisp pcase predicate pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching, elisp, predicate

I would like to pattern match on a few ranges of numbers, however it appears that elisp does not like the following expression:

```
(pcase (string-to-char (cadar parse))
  ((pred (and (>= (string-to-char "0")) (<= (string-to-char "5")))) do-something)
  ...
```

I've tested this out and it works fine with a single range, but when I start adding logical ORs and ANDS it does not work and I get the following error:

```
*** Eval error ***  Wrong number of arguments: >=, 1
```

I think it may have something to do with OR and AND being macros, but I have not learned how to use LISP macros yet...

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing two kinds of `and`: there's the `and` special form for Elisp expressions and there's the `and` special form for Pcase patterns.  So instead of `(pred (and A B))` (which will test if `(and A B <thevalue>)` returns non-nil) you want to use `(and (pred A) (pred B))`, which will test if `(and (A <thevalue>) (B <thevalue>))`.